Blazor Web Assembly Localization doesn't work on publish
I used Localization in my Blazor Wasm project. I set all the settings right (at least I think it's ok), and it works on debug as expected.
Program.cs :
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resource");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

Use in pages:
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization
@inject IStringLocalizer<App> Localizer
<p>@Localizer["Something"]</p>

But, when I publish it, I get this error in the console tab of my browser:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: VTable setup of type Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.ResourceManagerStringLocalizer failed
System.TypeLoadException: VTable setup of type Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.ResourceManagerStringLocalizer failed
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory.Create(Type )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.StringLocalizer`1[[ClientWebApp.App, ClientWebApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]..ctor(IStringLocalizerFactory factory)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InterpretedInvoke_Constructor(Object obj, IntPtr* args)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeDirectByRefWithFewArgs(Object , Span`1 , BindingFlags )
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithOneArg(Object , BindingFlags , Binder , Object[] , CultureInfo )
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags , Binder , Object[] , CultureInfo )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite , RuntimeResolverContext )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite , RuntimeResolverContext )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite , RuntimeResolverContext )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)

Does anybody know what is wrong with it?
I've tested this settings too, but I think it's for MVC.
        var supportedCultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("en-US"), new CultureInfo("fa") };
        var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
        };

        // Apply the localization options
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = localizationOptions.DefaultRequestCulture.Culture;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = localizationOptions.DefaultRequestCulture.UICulture;

